# Closure confusion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

Sample 1:http://jsfiddle.net/ufCr8/

```
function createFunctions() {
    var result = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        result[i] = function() {
            return i;
        }();
    }

    return result;
}

var funcs = createFunctions();       
for (var i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++) {
    document.write(funcs[i] + "<br />");
}
```

Sample 2:http://jsfiddle.net/T5shB/

```
function createFunctions() {
    var result = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        result[i] = function(num) {
            return function() {
                return num;
            };
        }(i);
    }

    return result;
}

var funcs = createFunctions();
for (var i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++) {
    document.write(funcs[i]() + "<br />");
}
```

Why do those two get different results?

Comment: They have the same result for me.

Comment: Yep, same result for me too. Are you using a strange browser?

Comment: I get the same result too.  Note that the functions are all executed inside the for loop, so the values assigned to `result[i]` are "frozen".  If you were to instead remove the `() `and run `result[i]()` outside the for loop, you would see a list of '9's printed out.

Comment: When you're asking questions about books, please include information about the work. It helps people help you, as well as correctly attributing the code. In this case, both examples are from *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, Second Edition* by Nicholas C. Zakas (Wrox, 2009), page 188.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These both work correctly. (And have the same results).

**Sample #1:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    result[i] = function() {
        return i;
    }(); // note function application!
}
```

The anonymous function is executed *right then* and the result is a number (the *current*) value of `i` each iteration through the loop. This is effectively the same as `result[i] = i`. Not very exciting. (In the loop that prints the value out, there is no function application, which would be an error as a number if not a function -- in this case it differs from the samples below.)

**Sample #2:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    result[i] = function(num) {
        return function() {
            return num;
        };
    }(i);
}
```

The outer anonymous function which is applied returns a closure which correctly "double-binds" to the *current value of `i`* which is passed in as `num` (`num` is actually the bound free-variable). Remember that functions introduce a new scope -- `var` (or `for`) does not.

**I suspect the "failing case" would be:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    result[i] = function() {
        return i;
    }; // note function NOT invoked here!
}

...
for (var i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++) {
    document.write(funcs[i]() + "<br />");
}
```

This will produce "odd results" because *it is the same `i` which is bound in each closure* (that is `i` is the free variable and *there is only one `i`*). Thus when the function is executed it will return the *current value of `i` at the point of execution*.

Happy coding

---

I would recommend reading the [Jibbering JavaScript Closure Notes](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) -- it's not the most beginner resource, but I find it accessible and it explains things in sufficient detail. (And is far, far more readable than the ECMAScript specification, IMOHO).

Comment: A perfect example of why it's good to use explicit parentheses around functions being immediately invoked, even if they are not necessary, as in this situation.